# Mac Notarization How to staple pkg file

Tags: macos

Issue : Mac stapling of pkg file fails with invalid file format.
I have prepared the Mac .pkg file for installation. I'm notarising this pkg file. It working fine.

Now i would like to staple the this pkg file. It fails with error `Invalid file format`.

```
xcrun stapler staple my.pkg
```

Any input on how to staple this pkg file ?

Tried to staple with command `scrub stapler staple my.pkg`

Comment: Is your .pkg a flat package? Is it code-signed?

Comment: I assume the `scrub stapler` is a typo, and that you mean `xcrun stapler`.

Answer (score 2):

You must wait until the notarization is complete before stapling. You can do that either by watching your email, or you can automate it in a makefile. Here's one way to automate the wait.

```
myRequestID=$(shell xcrun altool \
      --notarize-app \
      --primary-bundle-id $(BUNDLE_ID) \
      --username $(DEV_USERNAME) \
      --password $(DEV_PASSWORD) \
      --asc-provider $(DEV_PROVIDER) \
      --file my.pkg; \
\
while ! xcrun altool \
      --notarization-info $$myRequestID \
      --username $(DEV_USERNAME) \
      --password $(DEV_PASSWORD) \
      --asc-provider $(DEV_PROVIDER) \
      --output-format xml \
  | grep -q 'https://osxapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets' ;\
  do sleep 5 ;\
  echo "." ;\
done ;\
```

After waiting, you can staple.

```
xcrun stapler staple my.pkg
```

If this is still failing then it's a different issue. My first hunch would be that some component of the package is itself not signed and notarized. You need to notarize everything from the inside out.

You want to follow [Apple's notarization instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow), but pass the installer package to the `--file` argument.